# Replace dots with underscores in right part of the line

Tags: regex, sed

Say I have this piece of text:

```
some.blah.key={{blah.woot.wiz}}
some.another.foo.key={{foo.bar.qix.name}}
+ many other lines with a variable number of words separated by dots within {{ and }}
```

I'd like the following outcome after replacing dots with underscores in the right part (between the `{{` and `}}` delimiters):

```
some.blah.key={{blah_woot_wiz}}
some.another.foo.key={{foo_bar_qix_name}}
...
```

I'm looking for the appropriate regex to perform the replacement in a one-liner `sed`command`.

I'm on a lead with this one: https://regex101.com/r/8wsLHo/1 but it capture all dots, including those on the left part, which I don't want.
I tried this variation to exclude those on the left part but then it doesn't capture anything anymore: https://regex101.com/r/d7WAmX/1

Comment: Your delimiters are `{{` and `}}` so I assume you can have individual `{` or `}` chars within your text, e.g. `some.blah.key={{abc { def } ghi}}`, right? You should include that in your sample input/output or you'll get solutions that fail when that occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
sed ':a;s/\({{[^}]*\)\./\1_/;ta' file
```

`:a` defines a label "a"
`ta` jumps to "a" when something is replaced.

Comment: A very clever solution.

Comment: @Cyrus: Thanks <°))))))))>

Comment: I played with it and stripped it down a bit. To replace (with GNU sed) to the right of `=`: `sed -r ':a;s/(=.*)\./\1_/;ta' file` and left of `=`: `sed -r ':a;s/\.(.*=)/_\1/;ta' file`

Comment: Thank you, it did the job well. I'm curious if it's possible to do this with a single regex in say, Java, without resorting to sed additional semantic (loop here) ?

Comment: @GillesPhilippart: yes you can do it using the `\G` anchor. pcre: https://regex101.com/r/X7UIrS/1 or java: https://regex101.com/r/X7UIrS/2

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this quite complex one-liner:

```
sed "h;s/=.*/=/;x;s/.*=//;s/\./_/g;H;x;s/\n//"
```

explanations:

- `h`: put line in hold buffer
- `s/=.*/=/`: clobber right part after `=`
- `x`: swap to put line in main buffer again, first part in hold buffer
- `s/.*=//`: clobber left part before `=`
- `s/\./_/g`: perform replacement of dots now that there's only right part in main buffer
- `H`: append main buffer to hold buffer
- `x`: swap buffers again
- `s/\n//`: remove linefeed or both parts appear on separate lines

that was quite fun, but maybe `sed` is not the best tool to perform that operation, this rather belongs to [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)